# How to detect sails-hook-grunt signaling its `done` event?

Tags: node.js, gruntjs, sails.js

## Question Detour

I've found a way, I just don't know how to use it yet. My goal is to run some code when Grunt is done. I've discovered there's a `done` event -- it won't work for development but it will work for production, so that's fine.

## What I've Tried

- in the source of `sails-hook-grunt` I discovered mention of a `done` event but I don't know how to hook into it.
- `console.log(JSON.stringify(sails.hooks.grunt))` showed me there's a `routes.after` property but I don't know how to properly inject code into it.
- The object property `sails.grunt` doesn't exist nor does the global variable `grunt`

## Ideally

Since the only objection to using the `done` event is that the `watch` task never ends, the `done` event will work, if I can just figure out how to detect and respond to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it!

```
sails.on('hook:grunt:done', callback);
```

With the caveat that the `watch` task never ends during development, so you have to test in production mode or code for both scenarios.